# How to display the images stored in a list

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have stored images in a list but these images cannot be displayed by using the `display()`

I have unzipped the images in a folder and stored these images in a list. I'm trying to see the image so I used the `display()` method. The system shows me there is an attribute error.

```py
def unzip(path):
    """ return list of filenames inside of the zip folder"""
    global imglist 
    imglist= []
    global namelist 
    namelist= []
    with ZipFile(path, 'r') as imgzip:
        namelist = imgzip.namelist()
        for im in imgzip.infolist():
            with imgzip.open(im) as image:
                opened_image = Image.open(image)
                #display(opened_image)
                #saved_image  = opened_image.save("readonly/"+im.filename)
                imglist.append(opened_image)    
        return imglist,namelist


small = 'readonly/small_img.zip'    

Imlist,Nmlist=unzip(small)
display(Imlist[1])
```

the expected result is an RGB image but now the output is :

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'seek'

Comment: What is `display()`? Does your `Imlist` contain images?

Comment: I'm using jupyternotebook and Display() is used to show the image in the output. The Imlist does contain the information about the image

Comment: if I use print(Imlist), the output is:                   
 [<PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile image mode=RGB size=3600x6300 at 0x7FBE304289B0>, <PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile image mode=RGB size=3600x6300 at 0x7FBE303AD358>, <PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile image mode=RGB size=3600x6300 at 0x7FBE303AD7F0>, <PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile image mode=RGB size=7200x6300 at 0x7FBE303AD908>]

Answer (score 0):

Data is not actually read with [`Image.open`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.open):

> Opens and identifies the given image file.
>
> This is a lazy operation; this function identifies the file, but the
>   file remains open and the actual image data is not read from the file
>   until you try to process the data (or call the load() method).

When your script leaves context manager scope (`with imgzip.open(im) as image:`) the zip file is closed.